# How to manage Stock Of Product in ERP's?

Tags: spring-boot, erp

I want to make an ERP for Industries but I failed to manage stock of Product.So can any one suggest me about this

Comment: [did you try anything?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I tried by making database views. In that I made all views of consumption and Inward  and I did arithmetic operation on that So finally I got the latest Stock.But When I want to match any existing entry with stock then I failed In that way. Can you suggest me the better way then this ?          **@emotionlessbananas**

Comment: please be specific, where exactly you are getting problem with some code/uml or any related content. Otherwise this will be voted as close.